# Error: done() invoked with non-Error: {"req":{ ......} request done without error, but test didn't pass

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I'm trying to resolve my test but nothing seems to work. Currently I'm using mocha, supertest and chai, but even if request was performed successfully, I'm seeing this annoying error I can't get rid of:

> done() invoked with non-Error: {“req”:{ …} request done without error, but test didn't pass

Code:

```js
let should = require('chai').should(),
    expect = require('chai').expect,
    constants = require('./constants'),
    supertest = require('supertest'),
    api = supertest(constants.ENVIRONMENT),
    express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    request = require('request'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    assert = require('assert');
    
    describe('Create device API call', () => {

    function createToken() {
        return new Promise(resolve =>
            request.post(
                'myURl',
                { 
                 json: 
                        { 
                          "username": "myUsername", 
                          "password": "myPassword" 
                        } 
                },
                function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        let token = (body.accessList[0].accessToken);
                        resolve(token);

                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Server error get token")
                    }

                })
        )
    }

    it('should create device', async (done) => {

        let token = await createToken();

        //console.log(`Token is ${token}`);

        api.post('/deviceManifests/1/devices')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
            .send({
                "name": "QA integration",
                "deviceKey": "somekey38957",
                "defaultBinding": true
            })
            .expect('content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(201)
            .expect(function (res, err) {
                assert.equal(res.body.name, 'QA integration');

            }).then(done);
    });

});
```

Comment: Apart from changing the then to include the function or the arrow key func, add a catch block after .then for unresolved promise rejection. Don't assume that there are no errors without a catch for a promise reject scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much, in the meantime I solved it just like you said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing **done** into **then**.

Therefore, **done** will be passed an argument.

However, if you pass an argument to **done**, it expects it to be an error.

Try this instead:

```
.then(function () {
  done()
})
```

...or using an arrow function:

```
.then(() => done())
```

Comment: > it expects it to be an error

Yes, but what *is* an error? I keep gettin `done() invoked with non-Error` no matter what I pass to `done()`.

Comment: @yPhil This `done` callback accepts an instance of `Error` or a falsy value. Docs here: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to find out exactly what those two things are (Error instance (or subclass thereof) or a falsy value) notice that the docs don't provide any definition or link :( My app is throwing the error that gets passed on to `done()` so I need to know what an acceptable error *exactly* is ; like maybe a list. But Ok, I'll try `false`.

Comment: @yPhil Please see docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: @yPhil No problem :)